# Authenticate the user from SharePoint user group by using SP application page with MVC4

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, mvc

I have to authenticate the user from the SharePoint User Group and after the authentication navigate to the MVC Home page.
How to integrate the SharePoint application page and MVC Application ?
I mean how to create solution ?
Firstly SharePoint Solution and the add new project and add the MVC4 project in the same solution ?
Is it possible ?
Ram.

Comment: In page controller you could create class, that takes current logged user account (e.g. domain\login), checks user presence in specified SharePoint group and return view if user exist in group. Or redirect to page with message about wrong credentials or access denied. 
Please, explain if you need more info at particularly stage.